# Get count of Rows comparing column in one table from a field in another table with a join

Tags: mysql

I have a query that I'm trying to run that I need a count of all the rows in one table
where a column called score and I'm trying to get all the where the score is less the the column in another table without a join since they are not related by any field.

```
select count(*), item.score as score, `template`.`max_score` as max_score 
from `item` `template`
where score < max_score
```

score int value from 1 to 100 and in the other table it also has value 1 to 100. I'm only trying to get the rows that's less than the max values.

Could someone explain how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `JOIN`, using `score < max_score` as the relationship.

Then you need `GROUP BY` so you get a count per score.

```
select count(*), `template`.`max_score` as max_score 
from `item`
JOIN `template` ON item.score < template.max_score
GROUP BY template.max_score
```

You shouldn't include `item.score` in the `SELECT` list, since there will be many different scores that are less than the max.

You might also want `<=` instead of `<`. Otherwise, scores equal to the highest max score will not be counted.